# python xsd within soap response

Tags: python, soap, spyne, xmla

I'm using spyne for generating web services in the server side with python to communicate with an excel client (xmla plugin), and I have some difficulties to generate a soap response that match with the client request,
what I want is a soap response like this ( under **root** tag a **schema** with "**xsd:**" that refer to **xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema** in the **root** :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">
    <soap:Body>
       <DiscoverResponse xmlns="urn:...">
          <return> 
              <root xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                    xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset"
                    ....>

                  < xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset" 


                xmlns:sql="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-sql">
                <xsd:element name="root">
                <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:element name="row" type="row"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:simpleType name="uuid">
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:pattern value="[0-9a-zA-Z]{8}-[0-9a-zA-Z]{4}-[0-9a-zA-Z]{4}-[0-9a-zA-Z]{4}-[0-9a-zA-Z]{12}"/>
                </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:complexType name="xmlDocument">
                <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:any/>
                </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:complexType name="row">
                <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element sql:field="PropertyName" name="PropertyName" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element sql:field="PropertyDescription" name="PropertyDescription" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element sql:field="PropertyType" name="PropertyType" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element sql:field="PropertyAccessType" name="PropertyAccessType" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element sql:field="IsRequired" name="IsRequired" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element sql:field="Value" name="Value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:schema>

            </root>
        </return>
    </DiscoverResponse>
</soap:Body>
```

the result that i got with spyne every time doesn't contains the xsd: :

```
  <soap11env:Body>
<tns:DiscoverResponse>
  <tns:return>
    <ns2:root xmlns:ns2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset">
      <ns3:schema xmlns:ns3="services.models" targetNamespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset"/>
    </ns2:root>
  </tns:return>
</tns:DiscoverResponse>
```

here is my python code :
in models.py file:

```
class schema(ComplexModel):
targetNamespace = XmlAttribute(Unicode)
__type_name__ = "schema"

class DiscoverResponse(ComplexModel):
__namespace__ = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset"
root = Array(schema.customize(max_occurs='unbounded'))
```

in xmla.py file :

```
class xmla_provider(ServiceBase):

    @rpc(Unicode,
     Restrictionlist,
     Propertielist,
     _returns=[DiscoverResponse],
     _out_variable_names=["return"])

        def Discover(ctx, RequestType, Restrictions, Properties):
            response = DiscoverResponse()
            response.root = schema(targetNamespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset"),
            return response
```

to resolve the problem I tried to add 
    __ namespace __ = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
in **class schema** and i got this problem
    if child_ns != ns and not child_ns in self.imports[ns] and \
    KeyError: 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'

another solution that comes to mind and which is not a good solution, is to *force* a soap response by returning all

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset" 
            xmlns:sql="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-sql">....
```

to **root** attribut as Unicode
here is the code: 
in xmla.py

```
  response.root = "\n  < xsd:schema xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset' ....
```

in model.py

```
class DiscoverResponse(ComplexModel):
__namespace__ = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset"
root = Unicode
```

and I got this output

```
DEBUG:spyne.protocol.xml:Response <soap11env:Envelope xmlns:soap11env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">
 <soap11env:Body>
<tns:DiscoverResponse>
  <tns:return>
    <ns0:root xmlns:ns0="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset">

      &lt; xsd:schema xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
      xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset'
      xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
      xmlns:sql='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-sql' 

      ....

      /xsd:schema

  </ns0:root>
  </tns:return>
</tns:DiscoverResponse>
```

all < > characters are replaced by "& lt;" and "& gt;" 
(as I said this is not a good solution, normally I have to solve the problem with name spaces )

please any suggestion to solve the problem or in the worst case, any suggestion of soap library in python that allow this kind of response

Comment: I'm baffled that everyone as of late ask Spyne questions without a single speck of Spyne code in it. I need to see the code! The error! Come on guys, help me help you!

Comment: Did you set `_returns=AnyXml`? how are you generating the response?

Comment: sorry for not being clear, I updated my question @BurakArslan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch to bare mode and return `AnyXml` like this:

```
class DiscoverRequest(ComplexModel):
    RequestType = Unicode
    Restrictions = Restrictionlist
    Properties = Propertielist


class HelloWorldService(ServiceBase):
    @rpc(DiscoverRequest, _returns=AnyXml, _body_style="bare")
    def Discover(ctx, request):
        return etree.fromstring("""<root>whatever</root>""")
```